# Informatica cloud (IICS)

Tags: couchbase, iics

How can we create connection in IICS Informatica for Couchbase database and extract data from Couchbase to IICS Informatica  and is it possible in application integration also if yes than how can we create connection and extract data from Couchbase server to IICS  ?
Please share example and guidance for this issue

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you don't have luck getting an answer here on StackOverflow, you might try asking on the [Informatica Community discussion forum](https://network.informatica.com/s/).

Answer (score 1):

You would write code using the Couchbase SDK to read from Couchbase and write code using the Informatica SDK to write to Informatica.
You could also use the export data from Couchbase (in json or csv) and then import it into IICS Informatica according to the IICS Informatica documentation.